# Insert/Update, ignore rows which would violate FK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

If someone performs an update or insert on a table which has a foreign key to another, if a nonexistent value appears, an error is thrown. Is there an automated enough way to just ignore the faulty columns and continue with the others?

I can only think of an instead-of trigger, but it sounds messy.

Comment: You can remove the foreign key constraint so that records are always saved. But I would not advise you to do this. You can also handle the exception in your application.

Comment: There's no app, I'm an sql dev. As it is now, I probably have to read sys tables to draw the FK and add it dynamically to the spc

Comment: How do you update and insert? Are you using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the rows in your INSERT query, by joining the source data with the referenced table.

For example, let's suppose that you have the following data in the `SourceData` table and you want to insert it in the `Sales.CurrencyRate` table in the [AdventureWorks2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms) database:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceData (
    CurrencyRateDate datetime,
    FromCurrencyCode char(3),
    ToCurrencyCode char(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (CurrencyRateDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode),
    Rate money NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO SourceData (CurrencyRateDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode, Rate) VALUES 
('20200429','EUR','RON',4.8425),
('20200429','EUR','ROL',48425),
('20200430','EUR','RON',4.8421),
('20200430','EUR','ROL',48421)

INSERT INTO Sales.CurrencyRate (CurrencyRateDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode, AverageRate, EndOfDayRate)
SELECT sd.CurrencyRateDate, sd.FromCurrencyCode, sd.ToCurrencyCode, sd.Rate, sd.Rate
FROM SourceData sd
```

If you simply run the INSERT statement mentioned above, you would get an error saying `"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CurrencyRate_Currency_ToCurrencyCode". The conflict occurred in database "AdventureWorks2019", table "Sales.Currency", column 'CurrencyCode'."`, because the currency "RON" is not present in the `Sales.Currency` table.

To avoid this error and insert only the data that has corresponding rows in the referenced table, you would simply use a JOIN for each FK, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sales.CurrencyRate (CurrencyRateDate, FromCurrencyCode, ToCurrencyCode, AverageRate, EndOfDayRate)
SELECT sd.CurrencyRateDate, sd.FromCurrencyCode, sd.ToCurrencyCode, sd.Rate, sd.Rate
FROM SourceData sd
INNER JOIN Sales.Currency c1 ON c1.CurrencyCode=sd.FromCurrencyCode
INNER JOIN Sales.Currency c2 ON c2.CurrencyCode=sd.ToCurrencyCode
```